# Octave: Compute Gradient of a Multi-Dimensional Function at a particaular point

Tags: gradient, octave, function-handle

I have been trying out the following code to find the gradient of a function at a particular point where the input is a vector and the function returns a scalar.

The following is the function for which I am trying to compute gradient.

```
%fun.m    
function [result] = fun(x, y)
     result = x^2 + y^2;
```

This is how I call gradient.

```
f = @(x, y)fun(x, y);
grad = gradient(f, [1 2])
```

But I get the following error

```
octave:23> gradient(f, [1 2])
error: `y' undefined near line 22 column 22
error: evaluating argument list element number 2
error: called from:
error:    at line -1, column -1
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/general/gradient.m at line 213, column 11
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/general/gradient.m at line 77, column 38
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: `f = %(x, y)fun(x, y);`  That `%` should be an `@`, no?

Comment: yeah sorry, it should be @. Have made the edit.

Comment: can't you do :  `f = @(x,y) [x^2 + y^2];
grad = gradient(f(1, 2))`

Comment: @zeffii, I guess that would give the `0` vector (derivative of a constant).

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that `gradient` can't work on `2D` function handles, thus I made this. Consider the following *lambda-flavoring* solution:

Let `fz` be a function handle to some function of yours

```
fz = @(x,y)foo(x,y);
```

then consider this code

```
%% definition part:
only_x = @(f,yv) @(x) f(x,yv);  %lambda-like stuff, 
only_y = @(f,xv) @(y) f(xv,y);  %only_x(f,yv) and only_y(f,xv) are
                                %themselves function handles

%Here you are:
gradient2 =@(f,x,y) [gradient(only_x(f,y),x),gradient(only_y(f,x),y)];
```

which you use as

```
gradient2(fz,x,y);
```

Finally a little test:

```
fz = @(x,y) x.^2+y.^2
gradient2(f,1,2);
```

result

```
octave:17> gradient2(fz,1,2)
ans =

    2   4
```

Comment: informative answer, I've only just started to use Octave. loving all this vectorized stuff :)

Comment: @zeffii, indeed this is more kind of lambda (functional programming) stuff. But you can do a lot of vectorization either ;).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know we can write a separate script for computing gradient. But considering the fact that Octave is considered as an Open-Source alternative to MATLAB, I hoped that there should be an in-built way to compute Gradient for multi-dimensions.

Comment: @Karthik; W: How can you achieve that using matlab without additional toolboxes (optimization)?

Comment: @Acorbe: I just safely assumed that MATLAB has this functionality in-built. If not, both MATLAB and Octave need to seriously think about adding this functionality.

Comment: @Karthik, AFAIK Matlab doesn't have a built-in `gradient` function defined on function handles either.  `gradient` in MATLAB is defined just on matrices. It has been a surprise to me that octave has. BTW, to my knowledge, octave produces a 1D vector out of the 1D function handle and then performs a simple `diff` command. In more than 1D there would be ambiguity on the differentiation stencil pattern.